# How to replace 'MyFirstName' by 'My First Name'

Tags: apex, regular-expressions, string, replaceall

Is there any easy way, by using regex and replaceAll method, to tranform **MyFirstName** by **My First Name**. I know I could loop through each character but I was wondering if it was possible to do that in one line.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I will answer to my own question :

```
String text = 'ILikeSalesforcePlatform';
text = String.valueOf(text.splitByCharacterTypeCamelCase()).replaceAll('[\\,\\(\\)]','');
System.debug(text);
```

Output :

```
USER_DEBUG|[3]|DEBUG|I Like Salesforce Platform
```

Comment: Well now, that is so much easier. You had to throw me off the trail by mentioning regex...I forgot all about the splitByCharacterTypeCamelCase and just assumed you had already exhausted the string methods as available options...Thanks for the question and the answer. Helps everyone stay sharp

Comment: Thanks anyway for your answer. I hope this will help other people.

Comment: I love that Apex has [`splitByCharacterTypeCamelCase()`](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_string.htm#apex_System_String_splitByCharacterTypeCamelCase). Seems so specific.

Comment: Haha yeah sooo specific. Longest apex method name ?